# Checking if a UIViewController is about to get Popped from a navigation stack?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to know when my view controller is about to get popped from a nav stack so I can perform an action.

I can't use -viewWillDisappear, because that gets called when the view controller is moved off screen for ANY reason (like a new view controller being pushed on top).

I specifically need to know when the controller is about to be popped itself.

Any ideas would be awesome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though this question is 6 years old and answered, you still didn't read the second line in the question where I state "I can't use `-viewWillDisappear`, because that gets called when the view controller is moved off screen for ANY reason (like a new view controller being pushed on top)."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there is an explicit message for this, but you could subclass the UINavigationController and override - popViewControllerAnimated (although I haven't tried this before myself).

Alternatively, if there are no other references to the view controller, could you add to its - dealloc?

Comment: The dealloc will only be called *after* the pop, though, not before.

Comment: I don't think that's the best solution. I want to use this controller in other places in the app, and the behaviour I want to execute is specific to this controller and has to happen when the controller is popped. I don't want to have to subclass every navController this viewController appears in.

Comment: Try this: subclass UIViewController, override popViewController:animated: and send a custom message to the UIViewController's delegate. Then, the delegate can decide what it needs to do in each case.

Comment: Subclassing 'UINavigationController' will lead app to be rejected by apple. [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Subclass will not get you rejected by apple. Class is just not intended for subclassing because apple uses instances of NSNavigaionController that can't get access too, but there is inherently with subclassing.

Comment: @Alex UIViewController does not have the popViewController:animated: method.

Comment: @Jasarien On the method viewWillDisappear, One can use self.isMovingFromParent variable to check weather it is being popped or not.

Answer (score 92):

Override the `viewWillDisappear` method in the presented VC, then check the `isMovingFromParentViewController` flag within the override and do specific logic.  In my case I'm hiding the navigation controllers toolbar.  Still requires that your presented VC understand that it was pushed though so not perfect.

Comment: This is a clean solution in iOS 5+, and who isn't on iOS 5 at this point?

Comment: From Apple doc. "... For example, a view controller can
  check if it is disappearing because it was dismissed or popped by asking itself in its viewWillDisappear:
  method by checking the expression ([self isBeingDismissed] || [self isMovingFromParentViewController])"

Comment: Thanks @Pei for this comment. I will appreciate if you could add a link to this Apple doc.

Comment: It's actually from inside iOS SDK documentation. You can find this in line 229 to 232 of UIViewController.h as of Xcode 5.1.1.

Comment: Lines have changed to 270-275 as of Xcode 6.1.1 cc: @Pei

Comment: You may need to check `isMovingFromParentController` and `isBeingDismissed` both for the current view controller and all parents of the current view controller.

Answer (score 33):

Fortunately, by the time the viewWillDisappear method is called, the viewController has already been removed from the stack, so we know the viewController is popping because it's no longer in the **self.navigationController.viewControllers**

**Swift 4**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if let nav = self.navigationController {
        let isPopping = !nav.viewControllers.contains(self)
        if isPopping {
            // popping off nav
        } else {
            // on nav, not popping off (pushing past, being presented over, etc.)
        }
    } else {
        // not on nav at all
    }
}
```

**Original Code**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ((self.navigationController) && 
        (![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self])) {
        NSLog(@"I've been popped!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely the better answer here and one that works at the current time. Removes the need for subclassing, which whilst handy may be a bit over the top for some.

Comment: Calling `respondsToSelector` is unnecessary. `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` is supported by every UINavigationController.

Comment: Also, the predicate test is bad. It only checks if a controller with the same class is in the list, not if this specific controller is there. It would be better to use something simpler like: `[self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self]`

Comment: Jakob Egger is spot on. I've updated code per his suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Caoimhghin (and a fada over the last i to be precise) (pron: kwee-veen) - although I think I might use MattDiPasquale's override as it's a bit simpler

Answer (score 30):

Try overriding [`willMoveToParentViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:) (instead of `viewWillDisappear:`) in your custom subclass of `UIViewController`.

> Called just before the view controller is added or removed from a container view controller.

```
- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    [super willMoveToParentViewController:parent];
    if (!parent) {
        // `self` is about to get popped.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this is the way to go! Can't wait to try this. +1

Comment: Indeed! why would anyone use viewDidDisappear when it is so much less reliable than willMoveToParentViewController: Using iOS 8.4, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Another good thing about this method is that view controllers still has reference to the navigation controller (if it has one)

Comment: Would like to add that this is not as bulletproof as I first thought. Instead of overriding "willMoveToParentViewController", you should override "didMoveToParentViewController" with the same code inside. 

The reasoning behind this is that "willMoveToParentViewController" will fire-off even if the user did not COMPLETE the pop using the interactive gesture - you will get a false positive; on the other hand, "didMoveToParentViewController" will not fire until the full transition is complete.

Comment: also this fires when the controller appears as well as disappears

Answer (score 14):

This is working for me.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.parentViewController == nil) {
        NSLog(@"viewDidDisappear doesn't have parent so it's been popped");
        //release stuff here
    } else {
        NSLog(@"PersonViewController view just hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: also there's a side effect with full screen uipopovercontrollers  or modal view controllers appearing and triggering these.

Answer (score 9):

You can catch it here.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (viewController == YourAboutToAppearController) {
            // do something
    }
}
```

This will fire just before the display of the new View. Nobody's moved yet. I use all the time to do magic in front of the asinine NavigationController.  You can set titles and button titles and do whatever there.

Comment: My experimentation suggests that actually `[UINavigationController visibleViewController]` is already set to `YourAboutToAppearController`. Though indeed the animation has yet to start.

Comment: Using the UINavigationControllerDelegate seems like a better option than subclassing UINavigationController.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I tried with viewDisDisappear, but I don't have the function get called :( (don't know why, maybe because all my VC is UITableViewController).
The suggestion of Alex works fine but it fails if your Navigation controller is displayed under the More tab. In this case, all VCs of your nav controllers have the navigationController as UIMoreNavigationController, not the navigation controller you have subclassed, so you will not be notified by the nav when a VC is about to popped.
Finaly, I solved the problem with a category of UINavigationController, just rewrite - (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
   NSLog(@"UINavigationController(Magic)");
   UIViewController *vc = self.topViewController;
   if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllerWillBePopped)]) {
      [vc performSelector:@selector(viewControllerWillBePopped)];
   }
   NSArray *vcs = self.viewControllers;
   UIViewController *vcc = [vcs objectAtIndex:[vcs count] - 2];
   [self popToViewController:vcc animated:YES];
   return vcc;}
```

It works well for me :D

Comment: This is a great solution and not fragile at all as other suggestions. One could also use a Notification so anyone wanting to know about popped views could listen in.

Comment: Yes, this would be a good answer, super fast, without delegate, without notification.... thanks.   Adding the logic to the viewDidDisapper is not perfect, for example, when pushing or presenting another view controller inside it, the viewDidDisAppear will be invoked too....  This is why I really like this option.

Comment: Actually, subclass will be a better choice, or there will be a warning, but you can surpress it via: #pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"   ..........      #pragma clang diagnostic pop

Answer (score 2):

I tried this:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    // If we are disappearing because we were removed from navigation stack
    if (self.navigationController == nil) {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

The idea is that at popping, the view controller's navigationController is set to nil.
So if the view was to disappear, and it longer has a navigationController, I concluded it was popped. (might not work in other scenarios).

Can't vouch that viewWillDisappear will be called upon popping, as it is not mentioned in the docs. I tried it when the view was top view, and below top view - and it worked in both.

Good luck,
Oded.

Comment: An interesting idea and approach, but I fear it may be slightly too fragile. It relies on an implementation detail that could change at any time.

Comment: Agreed, hence that last skepticism.

Comment: Thanks Oded, that little snippet helped quite alot!

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `UINavigationController` and override `popViewController`:

#### Swift 3

```
protocol CanPreventPopProtocol {
    func shouldBePopped() -> Bool
}
  
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        let viewController = self.topViewController
        
        if let canPreventPop = viewController as? CanPreventPopProtocol {
            if !canPreventPop.shouldBePopped() {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    //important to prevent UI thread from freezing
    //
    //if popViewController is called by gesture recognizer and prevented by returning nil
    //UI will freeze after calling super.popViewController
    //so that, in order to solve the problem we should not return nil from popViewController
    //we interrupt the call made by gesture recognizer to popViewController through
    //returning false on gestureRecognizerShouldBegin
    //
    //tested on iOS 9.3.2 not others
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let viewController = self.topViewController
        
        if let canPreventPop = viewController as? CanPreventPopProtocol {
            if !canPreventPop.shouldBePopped() {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: If anyone have freezing issues after using above code, just leave a comment.

Comment: Should I have this issue? I don't see it now, but is it a possible bug?

Comment: @RoiMulia I had it during swipe gesture. In iOS 9.3.3. Check if you see that issue during swipe.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it closely

Comment: It's not freezing, but it's not calling UINavigationController popViewController method.. Did you fixed it?

Comment: @RoiMulia Hey, I updated the answer with the code I used. Seems that I had added a comment when I wrote the code.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me, but it did not work right out of box so I have changed it, and will post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
if(self.isMovingToParentViewController)
{
    NSLog(@"Pushed");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Popped");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to also prevent from popping sometimes so the best answer for me was written by Orkhan Alikhanov. But it did not work because the delegate was not set, so I made the final version:

```
import UIKit

class CustomActionsNavigationController: UINavigationController, 
                                         UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        if let delegate = topViewController as? CustomActionsNavigationControllerDelegate {
            guard delegate.shouldPop() else { return nil }
        }
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    // important to prevent UI thread from freezing
    //
    // if popViewController is called by gesture recognizer and prevented by returning nil
    // UI will freeze after calling super.popViewController
    // so that, in order to solve the problem we should not return nil from popViewController
    // we interrupt the call made by gesture recognizer to popViewController through
    // returning false on gestureRecognizerShouldBegin
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let delegate = topViewController as? CustomActionsNavigationControllerDelegate {
            if !delegate.shouldPop() {
                return false
            }
        }

        // This if statement prevents navigation controller to pop when there is only one view controller
        if viewControllers.count == 1 {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}

protocol CustomActionsNavigationControllerDelegate {
    func shouldPop() -> Bool
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have added `viewControllers.count == 1` case, because if there is one controller in the stack and user makes the gesture, it will freeze the UI of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the notification:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(navigationControllerWillShowViewController:) name:@"UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)navigationControllerDidShowViewController:(NSNotification *)notification{
    UIViewController *lastVisible = notification.userInfo[@"UINavigationControllerLastVisibleViewController"];
    if(lastVisible == self){
        // we are being popped
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    const BOOL removingFromParent = ![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self.parentViewController];
    if ( removingFromParent ) {
        // cleanup
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use UINavigationBarDelegate's navigationBar:shouldPopItem protocol method.

Comment: I tried that first. However, my Navigation Bar is managed by the navigation controller, and manually setting the delegate of the bar to be my view controller results in an exception that explains manually setting the delegate on the nav bar is not allowed if the bar is managed by a nav controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try making this check in viewwilldisappear
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound) {
//popping of this view has happend.
}