# Detecting when the 'back' button is pressed on a navbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to perform some actions when the back button(return to previous screen, return to parent-view) button is pressed on a Navbar.

Is there some method I can implement to catch the event and fire off some actions to pause and save data before the screen disappears?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting action for back button in navigation controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller)

Comment: Look at the [solution in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750456/exception-cannot-manually-set-the-delegate-on-a-uinavigationbar-managed-by-a-co/50925934#50925934)

Comment: I did it this way [show decision here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57137294/11079607)

Answer (score 324):

**UPDATE:** According to some comments, the solution in the original answer does not seem to work under certain scenarios in iOS 8+. I can't verify that that is actually the case without further details.

For those of you however in that situation there's an alternative. Detecting when a view controller is being popped is possible by overriding `willMove(toParentViewController:)`. The basic idea is that a view controller is being popped when `parent` is `nil`.

Check out ["Implementing a Container View Controller"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) for further details.

---

Since iOS 5 I've found that the easiest way of dealing with this situation is using the new method `- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController`:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

`- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController` makes sense when you are pushing and popping controllers in a navigation stack.

However, if you are presenting modal view controllers you should use `- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed` instead:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  if (self.isBeingDismissed) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10248412/592454), you could combine both properties:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController || self.isBeingDismissed) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Other solutions rely on the existence of a `UINavigationBar`. Instead like my approach more because it decouples the required tasks to perform from the action that triggered the event, i.e. pressing a back button.

Comment: I like you answer. But why did you use 'self.isBeingDismissed'? In my case, the statements in 'self.isBeingDismissed' do not get implemented.

Comment: @Rut `- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed` only makes sense when your view controller is presented and **dismissed** as a modal view controller. See this question for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10248412/592454

Comment: You say it's a method, but your code treats it as a property. Is there some equivalence in Objective-C such that 'if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController)' is treated as 'if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController])'?

Comment: @SteveCaine Yes, it's a compiler feature that translates the dot notation in a message. It's a controversial topic, because some claim this practice to be evil. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1249479/592454 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375991/592454

Comment: self.isMovingFromParentViewController appears to be false

Comment: @Sam Make sure you are calling `self.isMovingFromParentViewController` inside the correct methods. As stated in documentation _"This method returns YES only when called from inside the following methods:"_ `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:`. Also make sure that you are using a navigation controller, not presenting modal view controllers.

Comment: sorry, still no luck. I'm checking the value of isMovingFromParentViewController using LLDB aswell and it's no...

Comment: strange. on revisiting this it seems to be playing ball.

Comment: The only problem you can't use it if you want detect viewWillAppear while tab bar button press (: But it is very common case to separate navigation pop to root view controller from tab bar navigation.

Comment: `self.isMovingFromParentViewController` has TRUE value when I'm poping the navigation stack programmatically using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` - without any touch on the back button. Should I downvote your answer? (the subject says "'back' button is pressed on a navbar")

Comment: Didn't worked for me in iOS 8(.1). The view controller is in a navigation controller and the back button is pressed. Both boolean are false. It is in the correct method (`viewWillDisappear`). On iOS 7(.1) it worked. Perhaps it will work if you manually dismiss the view controller, but I use the tap of the user and the default back function. Now I'm using [this solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384144/426227).

Comment: Terrific answer, thank you very much. In Swift I used: `override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if isMovingFromParentViewController(){
            println("back button pressed")
        }
    }`

Comment: working on iOS7 but not on iOS8 ....
prefere :
if (self.navigationController.topViewController != self)
{
NSLog(@"is Poping")
}

Comment: For me, it was `isMovingToParentViewController` that worked.

Comment: You should only do this within `-viewDidDisappear:` since it's possible that you'll get a `-viewWillDisappear:` without a `-viewDidDisappear:` (like when you start swiping to dismiss a navigation controller item and then cancel that swipe.

Comment: Looks like not a reliable solution any more. Worked at the time I first used this (it was iOS 10). But now I accidentally found it calmly stopped working (iOS 11). Had to switch to the "willMove(toParentViewController)" solution.

Comment: It’s not out of date and it works fine under all scenarios. I don’t understand why you want to retract a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @matt. I've update the update (!) to better reflect the motivation for the alternative solution.

Comment: I want to confirm that solution works (self.movingFromParentViewController variant) as of today and as of iOS 12. Thanks @elitalon

Answer (score 106):

While `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidDisappear()` *are* called when the back button is tapped, they are also called at other times. See end of answer for more on that.

### Using UIViewController.parent

Detecting the back button is better done when the VC is removed from its parent (the NavigationController) with the help of `willMoveToParentViewController(_:)` OR `didMoveToParentViewController()`

If parent is nil, the view controller is being popped off the navigation stack and dismissed. If parent is not nil, it is being added to the stack and presented.

```
// Objective-C
-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
     [super willMoveToParentViewController:parent];
    if (!parent){
       // The back button was pressed or interactive gesture used
    }
}


// Swift
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)
    if parent == nil {
        // The back button was pressed or interactive gesture used
    }
}
```

Swap out `willMove` for `didMove` and check self.parent to do work *after* the view controller is dismissed.

### Stopping the dismiss

Do note, checking the parent doesn't allow you to "pause" the transition if you need to do some sort of async save. To do that you could implement the following. Only downside here is you lose the fancy iOS styled/animated back button. Also be careful here with the interactive swipe gesture. Use the following to handle this case.

```
var backButton : UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
     // Disable the swipe to make sure you get your chance to save
     self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
    
     // Replace the default back button
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    self.backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

// Then handle the button selection
func goBack() {
    // Here we just remove the back button, you could also disabled it or better yet show an activityIndicator
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    someData.saveInBackground { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            // Don't forget to re-enable the interactive gesture
            self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
        }
        else {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.backButton
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

### More on view will/did appear
If you didn't get the `viewWillAppear` `viewDidDisappear` issue, Let's run through an example. Say you have three view controllers:

1. ListVC: *A table view of things*
2. DetailVC: *Details about a thing*
3. SettingsVC: *Some options for a thing*

Lets follow the calls on the `detailVC` as you go from the `listVC` to `settingsVC` and back to `listVC`

**List > Detail** (push detailVC) `Detail.viewDidAppear` <- appear
**Detail > Settings** (push settingsVC) `Detail.viewDidDisappear` <- disappear

*And as we go back...*
**Settings > Detail** (pop settingsVC)  `Detail.viewDidAppear` <- appear
**Detail > List** (pop detailVC) `Detail.viewDidDisappear` <- disappear

Notice that `viewDidDisappear` is called multiple times, not only when going back, but also when going forward. For a quick operation that may be desired, but for a more complex operation like a network call to save, it may not.

Comment: Just a note, user `didMoveToParantViewController:` to do work when the view is no longer visible. Helpful for iOS7 with the interactiveGesutre

Comment: didMoveToParentViewController* there is a typo

Comment: Don't forget to call [super willMoveToParentViewController:parent]!

Comment: The parent parameter is nil when you are popping to the parent view controller, and non-nil when the view this method appears in is being shown. You can use that fact to do an action only when the Back button is pressed, and not when arriving at the view. That was, after all, the original question. :)

Comment: This also gets called when programmatically using `_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`, so it's not just called on a Back button press. I am looking for a call that works *only* when Back is pressed.

Comment: @EthanAllen The only way I can think of is the option under Stopping the dismiss

Answer (score 21):

Those who claim that this doesn't work are mistaken:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        print("we are being popped")
    }
}
```

That works fine. So what is causing the widespread myth that it doesn’t?

The problem seems to be due to an incorrect implementation of a *different* method, namely that the implementation of `willMove(toParent:)` forgot to call `super`.

If you implement `willMove(toParent:)` without calling `super`, then `self.isMovingFromParent` will be `false` and the use of `viewWillDisappear` will appear to fail. It didn't fail; you broke it.

**NOTE:** The real problem is usually the *second* view controller detecting that the *first* view controller was popped. Please see also the more general discussion here: [Unified UIViewController "became frontmost" detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602662/unified-uiviewcontroller-became-frontmost-detection)

**EDIT** A comment suggests that this should be `viewDidDisappear` rather than `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: This code is executed when the back button is tapped, but is also executed if the VC is popped programmatically.

Comment: @biomiker Sure, but that would also be true of the other approaches. Popping is popping. The question is how to detect a pop when you _didn't_ pop programatically. If you pop programatically you already _know_ you are popping so there is nothing to detect.

Comment: Yes, this is true of several of the other approaches and many of those have similar comments.  I was just clarifying since this was a recent answer with a specific rebuttal and I had gotten my hopes up when I read it.  For the record though, the question is how to detect a press of the back button.  It's a reasonable argument to say that code that will also execute in situations where the back button is not pressed, without indicating whether or not the back button was pressed, does not fully solve the real question, even if perhaps the question could have been more explicit on that point.

Comment: I think the main issue is that this method is also executed when another view controller is stacked on top of the current one

Comment: Unfortunately this returns `true` for the interactive swipe pop gesture - from the left edge of the view controller - even if the swipe didn't fully pop it. So instead of checking it in `willDisappear`, doing so in `didDisappear` works.

Comment: @badhanganesh Thanks, edited answer to include that info.

Comment: @MycroftCanner You're just repeating what was already discussed in the previous comments and added to the answer.

Comment: @badhanganesh That would seem to be a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 16):

**First Method**

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    if (![parent isEqual:self.parentViewController]) {
         NSLog(@"Back pressed");
    }
}
```

**Second Method**

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
       // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
       // in the navigation stack.  
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Second method was the only one that worked for me. First method was also called upon my view being presented, which wasn't acceptable for my use case.

Answer (score 9):

I've playing (or fighting) with this problem for two days. IMO the best approach is just to create an extension class and a protocol, like this:

```
@protocol UINavigationControllerBackButtonDelegate <NSObject>
/**
 * Indicates that the back button was pressed.
 * If this message is implemented the pop logic must be manually handled.
 */
- (void)backButtonPressed;
@end

@interface UINavigationController(BackButtonHandler)
@end

@implementation UINavigationController(BackButtonHandler)
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = self.topViewController;
    BOOL wasBackButtonClicked = topViewController.navigationItem == item;
    SEL backButtonPressedSel = @selector(backButtonPressed);
    if (wasBackButtonClicked && [topViewController respondsToSelector:backButtonPressedSel]) {
        [topViewController performSelector:backButtonPressedSel];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return YES;
    }
}
@end
```

This works because `UINavigationController` will receive a call to `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` every time a view controller is popped. There we detect if back was pressed or not (any other button).
The only thing you have to do is implement the protocol in the view controller where back is pressed.

Remember to manually pop the view controller inside `backButtonPressedSel`, if everything is ok.

If you already have subclassed `UINavigationViewController` and implemented `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` don't worry, this won't interfere with it.

You may also be interested in disable the back gesture.

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: This answer was almost complete for me, except that I found that 2 viewcontrollers would often be popped. Returning YES causes the calling method to call pop, so calling pop as well meant that 2 viewcontrollers would be popped. See this answer on another question for more deets (a very good answer that deserves more upvotes): http://stackoverflow.com/a/26084150/978083

Comment: Good point, my description was not clear about that fact. The "Remember to manually pop the view controller if everything is ok" it's only for the case of returning "NO", otherwise the flow is the normal pop.

Comment: For "else' branch, It's better to call super implementation if you don't want to handle pop yourself and let it return whatever it thinks is right, which is mostly YES, but it also takes care of pop itself then and animates chevron properly.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me in iOS 9.3.x with Swift:

```
override func didMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMoveToParentViewController(parent)

    if parent == self.navigationController?.parentViewController {
        print("Back tapped")
    }
}
```

Unlike other solutions here, this doesn't seem to trigger unexpectedly.

Comment: it is better to use willMove instead

Comment: Not sure about `willMove` as it might have the same problem as `willDisappear`: he user can start dismissing the view controller with a swipe, `willDisappear` will be called but the user can still cancel the swipe!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the back button callback, like this:

```
- (BOOL) navigationShouldPopOnBackButton
{
    [self backAction];
    return NO;
}

- (void) backAction {
    // your code goes here
    // show confirmation alert, for example
    // ...
}
```

for swift version you can do something like in global scope

```
extension UIViewController {
     @objc func navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() -> Bool {
     return true
    }
}

extension UINavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
     public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
          return self.topViewController?.navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() ?? true
    }
}
```

Below one you put in the viewcontroller where you want to control back button action:

```
override func navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() -> Bool {
    self.backAction()//Your action you want to perform.

    return true
}
```

Comment: Don't know why someone down voted. This seems to be by far best answer.

Comment: @Avinash Where does `navigationShouldPopOnBackButton` come from? It is not part of the public API.

Comment: @elitalon Sorry, this was half answer. I had thought remaining context was there in question. Anyway have updated the answer now

Comment: I agree. This is an underrated solution that uses the system back button with the "<" and the back menu. I always prefer to feed my code into the system callbacks where possible instead of imitating UI elements.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I think this is more of what he was looking for…

```
    UIBarButtonItem *l_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(backToRootView:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = l_backButton;


    - (void) backToRootView:(id)sender {

        // Perform some custom code

        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this solution is quite simple. Unfortunately, the icon is different. This is the "rewind" icon, not the back icon. Maybe there's a way to use the back icon...

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the UINavigationController delegate methods

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Using this you can know what controller is showing the UINavigationController.

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[HomeController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Show home controller");
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer! 
Might also want to add one more line just to remind folks --> 
self.navigationController.delegate = self;

Answer (score 2):

For Swift with a UINavigationController:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.navigationController?.topViewController != self {
        print("back button tapped")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [Pedro Magalhães](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4208335/pedro-magalh%C3%A3es) solution, except `navigationBar:shouldPop` was not called when I used it in an extension like this:

```
extension UINavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
 public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
      return self.topViewController?.navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() ?? true
}
```

But the same thing in a `UINavigationController` subclass worked fine.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
    return self.topViewController?.navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() ?? true
}
```

I see some other questions reporting this method not being called (but the other delegate methods being called as expected), from iOS 13?

[iOS 13 and UINavigationBarDelegate::shouldPop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166217/ios-13-and-uinavigationbardelegateshouldpop)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [UINavigationBarDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
In this case you might want to use the navigationBar:shouldPopItem: method.

Comment: This approach couples the viewControllers. so I believe It's not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

As Coli88 said, you should check the UINavigationBarDelegate protocol.

In a more general way, you can also use the `- (void)viewWillDisapear:(BOOL)animated` to perform custom work when the view retained by the currently visible view controller is about to disappear. Unfortunately, this would cover bother the push and the pop cases.

Answer (score 1):

As `purrrminator` says, the answer by `elitalon` is not completely right, since `your stuff` would be executed even when popping the controller programmatically.

The solution I have found so far is not very nice, but it works for me. Besides what `elitalon` said, I also check whether I'm popping programmatically or not:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  if ((self.isMovingFromParentViewController || self.isBeingDismissed)
      && !self.isPoppingProgrammatically) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

You have to add that property to your controller and set it to YES before popping programmatically:

```
self.isPoppingProgrammatically = YES;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding a UIControl to the navigationBar on the left side .

```
UIControl *leftBarItemControl = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 44)];
[leftBarItemControl addTarget:self action:@selector(onLeftItemClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.leftItemControl = leftBarItemControl;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:leftBarItemControl];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:leftBarItemControl];
```

And you need to remember to remove it when view will disappear:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.leftItemControl) {
        [self.leftItemControl removeFromSuperview];
    }    
}
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

[7ynk3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871166/7ynk3r)'s answer was really close to what I did use in the end but it needed some tweaks:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {

    UIViewController *topViewController = self.topViewController;
    BOOL wasBackButtonClicked = topViewController.navigationItem == item;

    if (wasBackButtonClicked) {
        if ([topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(navBackButtonPressed)]) {
            // if user did press back on the view controller where you handle the navBackButtonPressed
            [topViewController performSelector:@selector(navBackButtonPressed)];
            return NO;
        } else {
            // if user did press back but you are not on the view controller that can handle the navBackButtonPressed
            [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            return YES;
        }
    } else {
        // when you call popViewController programmatically you do not want to pop it twice
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.isMovingFromParentViewController is not working anymore on iOS8 and 9 I use :

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.navigationController.topViewController != self)
    {
        // Is Popping
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, some above methods worked before. However, today they all did not work anymore. Thus I have tried to find a solution.

The idea is that we may use a global-level counter. When a view controller appears, it will increase that global level and then assign it to an internal variant. By comparing that variant with the global level when appearing/disappearing it will know it is being popped to the parent.

I have created two view controller classes as below, one for UIViewController and the other for UITableViewController. All involved classes must be inherited from one of them. To detect popping, thus override the function "popping".

```
import UIKit

fileprivate var navLevel = 0

class GeneralViewController: UIViewController
{
    fileprivate var currentLevel = -1
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if currentLevel < 0 {
            navLevel += 1
            currentLevel = navLevel
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        
        if currentLevel == navLevel {
            navLevel -= 1
            currentLevel = -1
            popping()
        }
    }
    
    func popping() {
        print("popping", self, "currentLevel=", currentLevel, "navLevel=",navLevel)
    }
}

class GeneralTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    fileprivate var currentLevel = -1

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if currentLevel < 0 {
            navLevel += 1
            currentLevel = navLevel
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        
        if currentLevel == navLevel {
            navLevel -= 1
            currentLevel = -1
            popping()
        }
    }
    
    func popping() {
        print("popping", self, "currentLevel=", currentLevel, "navLevel=", navLevel)
    }
}

/////////////
class YourClass: GeneralViewController
{
    override func popping() {
        print("you are being popped")
    }

}
```

I think the solution is a bit ugly since I can't combine two classes into one (say, using generic programming) and we have to modify all involved classes (to inherit). Otherwise, the level counter may be messed up. I am not sure if it is OK for all cases of pushing/popping (you can help to detect and fix new problems).

But the most important it works now (at least for me) :)

Answer (score -1):

## (SWIFT)

finaly found solution.. method we were looking for is "willShowViewController" which is delegate method of UINavigationController

```
//IMPORT UINavigationControllerDelegate !!
class PushedController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //set delegate to current class (self)
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        //MyViewController shoud be the name of your parent Class
        if var myViewController = viewController as? MyViewController {
            //YOUR STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that it couples `MyViewController` to `PushedController`.