# isBeingDismissed not set in viewWillDisappear:

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have some code to clean up in my `viewWillDisappear:`, which I only want to use when the view is moving back to the parent view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController] || [self isBeingDismissed]) {
        NSLog(@"isMovingFromParentViewController or isBeingDismissed");
        // clean up
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

The view can be presented in two ways: it can be pushed by a navigation controller, or presented as a modal view controller (from the same navigation controller). If it's pushed, then popped (pressing the back button), my clean-up code runs. If it it presented as a modal view controller, then dismissed, the code doesn't run.

I dismiss like so:

```
[rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

My question is: why isn't `isBeingDismissed` set when I dismiss my view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is how you are dismissing your modal view. How is rootViewController being defined?

When I call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` then `[self isBeingDismissed]` evaluates to true.

When I call `[parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` then `[self isBeingDismissed]` evaluates to true, whereby parentViewController is the UIViewController that presented the modal view (note: not a UINavigationController).

Comment: I can confirm that `isBeingDismissed()` returns `false` when the viewController is supposedly popped from a `UINavigationController`, such as the detail viewController in a collapsed `UISplitViewController`.

Answer (score 35):

If this is the first view controller in a modal navigation controller that's being dismissed, calling `self.isBeingDimissed()` from `viewWillDisappear:` returns `false`.

However, since the entire navigation controller is being dismissed, what actually works is `self.navigationController?.isBeingDismissed()`, which returns `true`.

Answer (score 25):

As @Yuval Tal mentioned, this flag does not work when you're dismissing controller that is embeded inside navigation controller. Here's an extension that I use:

```
extension UIViewController 
{
    var isAboutToClose: Bool {
        return self.isBeingDismissed ||      
               self.isMovingFromParent ||          
               self.navigationController?.isBeingDismissed ?? false
    }
}
```

It can be easily extended when you find another case when standard `.isBeingDismissed` won't work. And if you find, let us, let me know in comments.

Answer (score 4):

If by some chance you came here trying to use `isBeingDismissed` on a non-modally presented view controller, you can always check the `topViewController` property of your `navigationController`, for instance:

```
if navigationController?.topViewController != self {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         viewController.isBeingPresented == NO;
>         [rootVC presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{
>             viewController.isBeingPresented == NO;
>             viewController.isBeingDismissed == NO;
>             [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
>                 viewController.isBeingDismissed == NO;
>             }];
>             viewController.isBeingDismissed == NO;    // is not work
>         }];
>         viewController.isBeingPresented == YES;     // is work
> ```

```
        viewController.isBeingPresented == NO;
        [rootVC presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{
            viewController.isBeingPresented == NO;
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                viewController.isBeingDismissed == NO;
                [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                    viewController.isBeingDismissed == NO;
                }];
                viewController.isBeingDismissed == YES;    // is work
            });
        }];
        viewController.isBeingPresented == YES;     // is work
```