# Presenting View Controller loses subviews when dismissing presented VC

Tags: ios

I'm having some trouble playing around with two viewcontrollers that interact in a straightforward manner:

The homeViewController shows a to-do list, with an addTask button.
The addTask button will launch an additional viewController that acts as a "form" for the user to fill.

However, upon calling

```
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

inside the **presented view controller** I return to my home page, but it's blank white and it seems nothing can be seen except the highest-level view on the storyboard can be seen (i.e. the one that covers the entire screen).

All of my views, scenes, etc. were set up with autolayout in storyboard. I've looked around on Stack Overflow, which lead to me playing around with the auto-resizing subview parameter i.e.:

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = false;
```

to no avail. I'm either fixing the auto-resizing parameter wrong (in the wrong view of interest, or simply setting it wrong), or having some other problem.

Thanks in advance

edit:

I present the VC as follows:

```
    func initAddNewTaskController(){
    let addNewTaskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddNewTaskViewController") as! AddNewTaskViewController;
    self.presentViewController(addNewTaskVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

edit2:

While I accept that using delegates or unwinding segue can indeed circumvent the problem I'm encountering (as campbell_souped suggests), I still don't understand what's fundamentally happening when I dismiss my view controller that causes a blank screen.

I understand that calling dismissViewControllerAnimated is passed onto the presenting view controller (in this case my homeViewController). Since I don't need to do any pre or post-dismissal configurations, the use of a delegate is (in my opinion) unnecessary here.

My current thought is that for some reason, when I invoke

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
```

in my addNewTaskViewController, it is actually releasing my homeViewController. I'm hoping someone can enlighten me regarding what it is exactly that I'm not understanding about how view controllers are presented/dismissed.

Comment: Can you show the way you present controller as a "form"?

Comment: edited original post; UI built with autolayout; not using delegation pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a situation like this, I usually take one of two routes. Either set up a delegate on `AddNewTaskViewController`, or use an unwind segue.

**With the delegate approach, set up a protocol:**

```
protocol AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate {
    func didDismissNewTaskViewControllerWithSuccess(success: Bool)
}
```

Add an optional property that represents the delegate in your `AddNewTaskViewController`

```
var delegate: AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate?
```

Then invoke the `didDismissNewTaskViewControllerWithSuccess` whenever you are about to dismiss `AddNewTaskViewController`:

If the record was added successfully:

```
self.delegate?.didDismissNewTaskViewControllerWithSuccess(true)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

Or if there was a cancelation/ failure:

```
self.delegate?.didDismissNewTaskViewControllerWithSuccess(false)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

Finally, set yourself as the delegate, modifying your previous snippet:

```
func initAddNewTaskController(){
    let addNewTaskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddNewTaskViewController") as! AddNewTaskViewController;
    self.presentViewController(addNewTaskVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

to this:

```
    func initAddNewTaskController() {
        guard let addNewTaskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddNewTaskViewController") as AddNewTaskViewController else { return }
        addNewTaskVC.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(addNewTaskVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

    ...
}

// MARK: AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate
extension homeViewController: AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate {

    func didDismissNewTaskViewControllerWithSuccess(success: Bool) {
        if success {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

[ Where the extension is outside of your `homeViewController` class ]

**With the unwind segue approach, take a look at this Ray Wenderlich example:**
http://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

This approach involves Ctrl-dragging from your IBAction to the exit object above the view controller and then picking the correct action name from the popup menu

Comment: thanks for the answer! another question i have is what's the fundamental difference between using a delegate to do this, or lack thereof?

Comment: Simply put, the delegate pattern is way more robust. You can add additional functions or even add more parameters to the `didDismissNewTaskViewControllerWithSuccess` function.

Comment: Do you know what might be causing my problem by simply dismissing the view controller?

Comment: are you dismissing the `homeViewController` or the `AddNewTaskViewController`?

Comment: How can I tell which one I'm dismissing? The func doesn't take a view controller as input, and judging from its documentation, I should be dismissing AddNewTaskViewController, since it is (at least I think it is) unambiguously the only view controller that has been presented

Comment: if you invoke `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)` directly it is dismissing the view controller for the current class you are in

Comment: Yes that would be the AddNewTaskViewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99563/discussion-between-campbell-souped-and-user3605508).