# Adding Notification for DismissViewController without Subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a ViewController that I am presenting currently.

So lets say VC2 is being presented on VC1. Without Subclassing VC2 is there a way to be notified on VC1 that VC2 got dismissed? I don't want to create a subclass of ViewController just to acknowledge the dismissal of the ViewController for tracking purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: On `VC2`, you can get `VC1` by using `self.presentingViewController` and do whatever you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when a presented view controller is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853212/detect-when-a-presented-view-controller-is-dismissed)

Answer (score 0):

You can try in VC1

```
var count = 0

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   count+=1

    if(count == 2) {
       // dismiss of VC2
    }

 }
```