# view(Will/Did)Disappear not called when using modalPresentationStyle = formSheet

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a UIViewController, `MainViewController`, that presents a `SheetViewController` using `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet`. `SheetViewController` then presents another ViewController using `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`. Doing this causes `viewWillDisappear()` to be called on `SheetViewController`, but never on `MainViewController`.

Since I have some frequent calls to a backend in `MainViewController`, I want to be informed when it is not visible, such that I can stop these calls. This *could* be done using delegates, but can it really be that there is no way that `MainViewController` can be informed directly by iOS when it is no longer visible on the screen?

Comment: Here is some sample code demoing the problem: https://gist.github.com/johan-mjolner/26b8d5fad2aa9cd3e520411576787750

Comment: II'd use a simple closure to do so https://stackoverflow.com/a/45619821/1801544

Comment: I know, but I would rather like iOS to inform me if possible - there are a LOT of classes involved in my legacy app, so I would rather not use a closure or delegates...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how you are manipulating the view hierarchy.

If you present a VC using `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`, UIKit removes the ***presenting*** controller.

If you present a VC using `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet`, UIKit **DOES NOT** remove the ***presenting*** controller.

So...

From MainVC, present SheetVC as `.formSheet` ... MainVC is still in the hierarchy.

From SheetVC, present FullScreenVC as `.fullScreen` ... SheetVC is the *presenting* controller, so it is removed from the hierarchy -- but MainVC is still where it was.

When you `dismiss` FullScreenVC, SheetVC is again *added* to the view hierarchy, on top of MainVC.