# Execute action when back bar button of UINavigationController is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I need to execute an action (emptying an array), when the back button of a `UINavigationController` is pressed, while the button still causes the previous `ViewController` on the stack to appear. How could I accomplish this using swift?  [image]

Answer (score 185, accepted):

One option would be implementing your own custom back button. You would need to add the following code to your viewDidLoad method:

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(back:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
    }

    - (void) back:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
        // Perform your custom actions
        // ...
        // Go back to the previous ViewController
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the version for Swift:

```
        override func viewDidLoad {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
            let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "back:")
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
        }

       @objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            // Perform your custom actions
            // ...
            // Go back to the previous ViewController
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the version for Swift 3:

```
        override func viewDidLoad {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
            let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.back(sender:)))
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
        }

       @objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            // Perform your custom actions
            // ...
            // Go back to the previous ViewController
            _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't pop to the previous view controller; it pops to the root view controller.

Comment: @rocky You may try the below line in back function:    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: it's work but we will lost swipe back action

Answer (score 566):

Replacing the button to a custom one as suggested on another answer is possibly not a great idea as you will lose the default behavior and style.

One other option you have is to implement the **viewWillDisappear** method on the View Controller and check for a property named **isMovingFromParentViewController**. If that property is true, it means the View Controller is disappearing because it's being removed (popped).

Should look something like:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingFromParentViewController {
        // Your code...
    }
}
```

## In swift 4.2

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        // Your code...
    }
}
```

Comment: For **Swift 3.1**:
`override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if isMovingFromParentViewController {
        // Your code...
    }
}`

Comment: ```viewWillDisappear(animated:)``` will get triggered if you get a phone call. This is likely not what you want. Probably better to use ```willMove(toParentViewController:)```

Comment: in Swift 4, missing _: override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool)

Comment: No this is totally wrong This method is called when back button is press and we pop to ViewController then this method is called question is to how to do action in NavigationItem BackButton Click. This is like completion and we can do this thing in ViewWillDisappear. I hope you got what I am telling you. is there is any way to do button click then please give me solution. Thank You

Comment: unfortunately this also gets called when going to any moving to any new view controller... but I need to only capture the back button and nothing else

Comment: How has this got so much upvotes?  question is rather than default behaviour need to  detect when back button is tapped & do action...  self.isMovingFromParent will always return true if user has navigated in this page..

Answer (score 78):

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?)
{
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)
    if parent == nil
    {
        print("This VC is 'will' be popped. i.e. the back button was pressed.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working in Swift3/iOS10, console prints 'nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar'.

Comment: Not getting called at all

Comment: This is also getting called when moving into a new VC, not just when going back.

Comment: As per @JozemiteApps comment, it's in the docs  _Called just before the view controller is added or removed from a container view controller._.

Comment: UIViewController.willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) is called when the ViewController is moved to a container ViewController, it has no relation with navigation.

Comment: Note that this is also called when you pop programmatically, not only press back button.

Answer (score 43):

I was able to achieve this with the following :

**Swift 3**

```
override func didMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
   super.didMoveToParentViewController(parent)

   if parent == nil {
      println("Back Button pressed.")
      delegate?.goingBack()
   }           
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParent: parent)

    if parent == nil {
        debugPrint("Back Button pressed.")
    }
}
```

No need of custom back button.

Comment: This is triggered (false positive) also when unwinding from next view controller (over this one) so not really back button press detection.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to have back button with back arrow you can use an image and code below

backArrow.png [image: arrow1] backArrow@2x.png [image: arrow2] backArrow@3x.png [image: arrow3]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backArrow") , style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backAction(sender:)))
    customBackButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton
}

func backAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // custom actions here
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: For iOS16, SF symbol "chevron.backward" matchs the default image even more. 
`let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .semibold))`

Answer (score 31):

I created this (swift) class to create a back button exactly like the regular one, including back arrow. It can create a button with regular text or with an image.

**Usage**

```
weak var weakSelf = self

// Assign back button with back arrow and text (exactly like default back button)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = CustomBackButton.createWithText("YourBackButtonTitle", color: UIColor.yourColor(), target: weakSelf, action: #selector(YourViewController.tappedBackButton))

// Assign back button with back arrow and image
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = CustomBackButton.createWithImage(UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!, color: UIColor.yourColor(), target: weakSelf, action: #selector(YourViewController.tappedBackButton))

func tappedBackButton() {

    // Do your thing

    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

**CustomBackButtonClass**

(code for drawing the back arrow created with Sketch & Paintcode plugin)

```
class CustomBackButton: NSObject {

    class func createWithText(text: String, color: UIColor, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) -> [UIBarButtonItem] {
        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -8
        let backArrowImage = imageOfBackArrow(color: color)
        let backArrowButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backArrowImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: target, action: action)
        let backTextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: text, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain , target: target, action: action)
        backTextButton.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -12.0, vertical: 0.0), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        return [negativeSpacer, backArrowButton, backTextButton]
    }

    class func createWithImage(image: UIImage, color: UIColor, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) -> [UIBarButtonItem] {
        // recommended maximum image height 22 points (i.e. 22 @1x, 44 @2x, 66 @3x)
        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -8
        let backArrowImageView = UIImageView(image: imageOfBackArrow(color: color))
        let backImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let customBarButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,22 + backImageView.frame.width,22))
        backImageView.frame = CGRectMake(22, 0, backImageView.frame.width, backImageView.frame.height)
        customBarButton.addSubview(backArrowImageView)
        customBarButton.addSubview(backImageView)
        customBarButton.addTarget(target, action: action, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return [negativeSpacer, UIBarButtonItem(customView: customBarButton)]
    }

    private class func drawBackArrow(frame frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 14, height: 22), color: UIColor = UIColor(hue: 0.59, saturation: 0.674, brightness: 0.886, alpha: 1), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .AspectFit) {
        /// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        /// Resize To Frame
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        let resizedFrame = resizing.apply(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 14, height: 22), target: frame)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, resizedFrame.minX, resizedFrame.minY)
        let resizedScale = CGSize(width: resizedFrame.width / 14, height: resizedFrame.height / 22)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, resizedScale.width, resizedScale.height)

        /// Line
        let line = UIBezierPath()
        line.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 9, y: 9))
        line.addLineToPoint(CGPoint.zero)
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 3, 11)
        line.lineCapStyle = .Square
        line.lineWidth = 3
        color.setStroke()
        line.stroke()
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)

        /// Line Copy
        let lineCopy = UIBezierPath()
        lineCopy.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 9, y: 0))
        lineCopy.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 9))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 3, 2)
        lineCopy.lineCapStyle = .Square
        lineCopy.lineWidth = 3
        color.setStroke()
        lineCopy.stroke()
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)

        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

    private class func imageOfBackArrow(size size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 14, height: 22), color: UIColor = UIColor(hue: 0.59, saturation: 0.674, brightness: 0.886, alpha: 1), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .AspectFit) -> UIImage {
        var image: UIImage

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        drawBackArrow(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size), color: color, resizing: resizing)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    private enum ResizingBehavior {
        case AspectFit /// The content is proportionally resized to fit into the target rectangle.
        case AspectFill /// The content is proportionally resized to completely fill the target rectangle.
        case Stretch /// The content is stretched to match the entire target rectangle.
        case Center /// The content is centered in the target rectangle, but it is NOT resized.

        func apply(rect rect: CGRect, target: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            if rect == target || target == CGRect.zero {
                return rect
            }

            var scales = CGSize.zero
            scales.width = abs(target.width / rect.width)
            scales.height = abs(target.height / rect.height)

            switch self {
                case .AspectFit:
                    scales.width = min(scales.width, scales.height)
                    scales.height = scales.width
                case .AspectFill:
                    scales.width = max(scales.width, scales.height)
                    scales.height = scales.width
                case .Stretch:
                    break
                case .Center:
                    scales.width = 1
                    scales.height = 1
            }

            var result = rect.standardized
            result.size.width *= scales.width
            result.size.height *= scales.height
            result.origin.x = target.minX + (target.width - result.width) / 2
            result.origin.y = target.minY + (target.height - result.height) / 2
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
class CustomBackButton: NSObject {

    class func createWithText(text: String, color: UIColor, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) -> [UIBarButtonItem] {
        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -8
        let backArrowImage = imageOfBackArrow(color: color)
        let backArrowButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backArrowImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: target, action: action)
        let backTextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: text, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain , target: target, action: action)
        backTextButton.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -12.0, vertical: 0.0), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        return [negativeSpacer, backArrowButton, backTextButton]
    }

    class func createWithImage(image: UIImage, color: UIColor, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) -> [UIBarButtonItem] {
        // recommended maximum image height 22 points (i.e. 22 @1x, 44 @2x, 66 @3x)
        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -8
        let backArrowImageView = UIImageView(image: imageOfBackArrow(color: color))
        let backImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let customBarButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22 + backImageView.frame.width, height: 22))
        backImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 22, y: 0, width: backImageView.frame.width, height: backImageView.frame.height)
        customBarButton.addSubview(backArrowImageView)
        customBarButton.addSubview(backImageView)
        customBarButton.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
        return [negativeSpacer, UIBarButtonItem(customView: customBarButton)]
    }

    private class func drawBackArrow(_ frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 14, height: 22), color: UIColor = UIColor(hue: 0.59, saturation: 0.674, brightness: 0.886, alpha: 1), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .AspectFit) {
        /// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        /// Resize To Frame
        context.saveGState()
        let resizedFrame = resizing.apply(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 14, height: 22), target: frame)
        context.translateBy(x: resizedFrame.minX, y: resizedFrame.minY)
        let resizedScale = CGSize(width: resizedFrame.width / 14, height: resizedFrame.height / 22)
        context.scaleBy(x: resizedScale.width, y: resizedScale.height)

        /// Line
        let line = UIBezierPath()
        line.move(to: CGPoint(x: 9, y: 9))
        line.addLine(to: CGPoint.zero)
        context.saveGState()
        context.translateBy(x: 3, y: 11)
        line.lineCapStyle = .square
        line.lineWidth = 3
        color.setStroke()
        line.stroke()
        context.restoreGState()

        /// Line Copy
        let lineCopy = UIBezierPath()
        lineCopy.move(to: CGPoint(x: 9, y: 0))
        lineCopy.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 9))
        context.saveGState()
        context.translateBy(x: 3, y: 2)
        lineCopy.lineCapStyle = .square
        lineCopy.lineWidth = 3
        color.setStroke()
        lineCopy.stroke()
        context.restoreGState()

        context.restoreGState()
    }

    private class func imageOfBackArrow(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 14, height: 22), color: UIColor = UIColor(hue: 0.59, saturation: 0.674, brightness: 0.886, alpha: 1), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .AspectFit) -> UIImage {
        var image: UIImage

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        drawBackArrow(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size), color: color, resizing: resizing)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    private enum ResizingBehavior {
        case AspectFit /// The content is proportionally resized to fit into the target rectangle.
        case AspectFill /// The content is proportionally resized to completely fill the target rectangle.
        case Stretch /// The content is stretched to match the entire target rectangle.
        case Center /// The content is centered in the target rectangle, but it is NOT resized.

        func apply(_ rect: CGRect, target: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            if rect == target || target == CGRect.zero {
                return rect
            }

            var scales = CGSize.zero
            scales.width = abs(target.width / rect.width)
            scales.height = abs(target.height / rect.height)

            switch self {
            case .AspectFit:
                scales.width = min(scales.width, scales.height)
                scales.height = scales.width
            case .AspectFill:
                scales.width = max(scales.width, scales.height)
                scales.height = scales.width
            case .Stretch:
                break
            case .Center:
                scales.width = 1
                scales.height = 1
            }

            var result = rect.standardized
            result.size.width *= scales.width
            result.size.height *= scales.height
            result.origin.x = target.minX + (target.width - result.width) / 2
            result.origin.y = target.minY + (target.height - result.height) / 2
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @guido, your solution is perfect, I tried your code and noticed that there is space in front of back button even though you added barbutton with negative width.

Answer (score 23):

In Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2

Please don't add custom bar button item, use this default behaviour.

No need of **viewWillDisappear**, no need of **custom BarButtonItem** etc...

It's better to detect when the VC is removed from it's parent.

Use any one of these two functions

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)
    if parent == nil {
        callStatusDelegate?.backButtonClicked()//Here write your code
    }
}

override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParent: parent)
    if parent == nil {
        callStatusDelegate?.backButtonClicked()//Here write your code
    }
}
```

If you want stop default behaviour of back button then add custom BarButtonItem.

Comment: Note that this is also called when you pop programmatically, not only press back button.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `navigationController` then add the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol to class and add the delegate method as follows:

```
class ViewController:UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController,
animated: Bool) {
        if viewController === self {
            // do here what you want
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called whenever the navigation controller will slide to a new screen. If the back button was pressed, the new view controller is `ViewController` itself.

Comment: Which becomes horrible when using a non NSObjectProtocol class as a delegate.

Comment: It is not always called when back button is pressed.

Answer (score 9):

You can subclass `UINavigationController` and override `popViewController(animated: Bool)`. Beside being able to execute some code there you can also prevent the user from going back altogether, for instance to prompt to save or discard his current work.

Sample implementation where you can set a `popHandler` that gets set/cleared by pushed controllers.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController
{
    var popHandler: (() -> Bool)?

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController?
    {
        guard self.popHandler?() != false else
        {
            return nil
        }
        self.popHandler = nil
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }
}
```

And sample usage from a pushed controller that tracks unsaved work.

```
let hasUnsavedWork: Bool = // ...
(self.navigationController as! NavigationController).popHandler = hasUnsavedWork ?
    {
        // Prompt saving work here with an alert

        return false // Prevent pop until as user choses to save or discard

    } : nil // No unsaved work, we clear popHandler to let it pop normally
```

As a nice touch, this will also get called by `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` when the user tries to go back using a swipe gesture.

Answer (score 7):

**NO**

`override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) { }`

This will get called even if you are segueing **to** the view controller in which you are overriding this method. In which check if the "`parent`" is `nil` of not is not a precise way to be sure of moving *back* to the correct `UIViewController`. To determine exactly if the `UINavigationController` is properly navigating back to the `UIViewController` that presented this current one, you will need to conform to the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol.

**YES**

*note: `MyViewController` is just the name of whatever `UIViewController` you want to detect going back from.*

1) At the top of your file add `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

2) Add a property to your class that will keep track of the `UIViewController` that you are segueing from.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var previousViewController:UIViewController
```

3) in `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method assign `self` as the delegate for your `UINavigationController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

3) **Before you segue**, assign the previous `UIViewController` as this property.

```
// In previous UIViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueID" {
        if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? MyViewController {
            nextViewController.previousViewController = self
        }
    }
}
```

4) And conform to one method in `MyViewController` of the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewController == self.previousViewController {
        // You are going back
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer!

Readers beware of setting the UINavigationController's delegate to a specific view controller; if the navigation controller already has a delegate, you run the risk of depriving that other delegate of callbacks it expects.

In our app, the UINavigationController's delegate is a shared object (an AppCoordinator) that all view controllers have a pointer to.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the `viewWillDisappear` worked best. But in some cases one has to modify the previous view controller. So here is my solution with access to the **previous view controller** and it works in **Swift 4**:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if isMovingFromParentViewController {
            if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
                if (viewControllers.count >= 1) {
                    let previousViewController = viewControllers[viewControllers.count-1] as! NameOfDestinationViewController
                    // whatever you want to do
                    previousViewController.callOrModifySomething()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: -viewDidDisappear (or -viewWillDisappear) will be called even if the view is being covered by another view controller's view (not just when the <Back button is pressed), hence the need to check isMovingFromParentViewController.

Answer (score 7):

Before leave current controller I need to show alert. So I did it this way:

1. Add extention to `UINavigationController` with `UINavigationBarDelegate`
2. Add selector to your controller **navigationShouldPopOnBack(completion:)**

It's worked)

```
extension UINavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        if let items = navigationBar.items, viewControllers.count < items.count {
            return true
        }

        let clientInfoVC = topViewController as? ClientInfoVC
        if clientInfoVC?.responds(to: #selector(clientInfoVC?.navigationShouldPopOnBack)) ?? false {
            clientInfoVC?.navigationShouldPopOnBack(completion: { isAllowPop in
                if isAllowPop {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.popViewController(animated: true)
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.popViewController(animated: true)
        }

        return false
    }
}

@objc func navigationShouldPopOnBack(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: R.string.alert.actionOk(), style: .default) { _ in
            completion(true)
        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: R.string.alert.actionCancel(), style: .cancel) { _ in
            completion(false)
        }
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: R.string.alert.contractMessage(), preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(ok)
        alertController.addAction(cancel)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

When back button is pressed, ignore interactive pop with screen edge gesture.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    if isMovingFromParent, transitionCoordinator?.isInteractive == false {
      // code here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not difficult as we thing. Just create a frame for UIButton with clear background color, assign action for the button and place over the navigationbar back button. And finally remove the button after use.

Here is the Swift 3
sample code done with UIImage instead of UIButton

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:2*(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)!,height:(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)!)
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(back(sender:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imageView.tag = 1
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)
    }
```

write the code need  to be executed

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Perform your custom actions}
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
```

Remove the subView after action is performed

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    for view in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)!{
        if view.tag == 1 {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in iOS 11. Not when the UIImageView's background colour is clear. Set it to a different colour and it works.

Comment: We can define a UIImageView with clear color, set its frame, assign tapgesture and place anywhere in the screen. Then why can't we place it over a navigation bar. 
To be sincere I won't recommend what I wrote . If there is an issue definitely there is a reason but it is not the color matters.
Forget the code follow the logic u will succeed. :)

Answer (score 5):

For **Swift 5**, we can check it in view will disappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        delegate?.passValue(clickedImage: selectedImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution

```
extension UINavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        if let shouldBlock = self.topViewController?.shouldPopFromNavigation() {
            return shouldBlock
        }
        return true
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    @objc func shouldPopFromNavigation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

In your view controller, you can handle like this:

```
@objc override func shouldPopFromNavigation() -> Bool {
        // Your dialog, example UIAlertViewController or whatever you want
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 4.2:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        // Your code...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 5 __ Xcode 11.5

In my case I wanted to make an animation, and when it finished, go back.
A way to overwrite the default action of the back button
and call your custom action is this:

```
     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setBtnBack()
    }

    private func setBtnBack() {
        for vw in navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews ?? [] where "\(vw.classForCoder)" == "_UINavigationBarContentView" {
            print("\(vw.classForCoder)")
            for subVw in vw.subviews where "\(subVw.classForCoder)" == "_UIButtonBarButton" {
                let ctrl = subVw as! UIControl
                ctrl.removeTarget(ctrl.allTargets.first, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
                ctrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backBarBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
        }
    }


    @objc func backBarBtnAction() {
        doSomethingBeforeBack { [weak self](isEndedOk) in
            if isEndedOk {
                self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }


    private func doSomethingBeforeBack(completion: @escaping (_ isEndedOk:Bool)->Void ) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.vwTxt.alpha = 0
        }) { (isEnded) in
            completion(isEnded)
        }
    }
```

[image: NavigationBar view hierarchy]

Or you can use this method one time to explore the NavigationBar view hierarchy, and get the indexes to access to the _UIButtonBarButton view, cast to UIControl, remove the target-action, and add your custom targets-actions:

```
    private func debug_printSubviews(arrSubviews:[UIView]?, level:Int) {
        for (i,subVw) in (arrSubviews ?? []).enumerated() {
            var str = ""
            for _ in 0...level {
                str += "\t"
            }
            str += String(format: "%2d %@",i, "\(subVw.classForCoder)")
            print(str)
            debug_printSubviews(arrSubviews: subVw.subviews, level: level + 1)
        }
    }

    // Set directly the indexs
    private func setBtnBack_method2() {
        // Remove or comment the print lines
        debug_printSubviews(arrSubviews: navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews, level: 0)   
        let ctrl = navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[1].subviews[0] as! UIControl
        print("ctrl.allTargets: \(ctrl.allTargets)")
        ctrl.removeTarget(ctrl.allTargets.first, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
        print("ctrl.allTargets: \(ctrl.allTargets)")
        ctrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backBarBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        print("ctrl.allTargets: \(ctrl.allTargets)")
    }
```

Comment: This works as expected, but in iOS 15 when I tap and hold the back button it pops up the menu actions and executes the back action.

Comment: Clever but you are REALLY playing with fire/begging for trouble to create solutions that dig that far into the undocumented implementation! It could change at any time, any update, release and break your app.  Almost every time I try to get super clever and complicated and go under the hood to solve a problem it's not worth it, and there's usually a better design under the circumstances that I'm stubbornly refusing to see and appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)

    if parent == nil{
        print("Back button was clicked")
    }
}
```

Comment: -did/willMove(toParentViewController:) is possibly better than checking isMovingTfromParentViewController in -viewWillDisappear since it is only called when the view controller is actually changing parents (not when the view is covered by another VC's view)

But the more "correct" solution is to implement the UINavigationController delegate method. Be careful, though; if the NavigationController already has a delegate, you run the risk of depriving that other delegate of callbacks it expects.

Comment: I tested with a splitViewController. There, could not make the difference between added or removed.

Answer (score 3):

just do control + drag the bar item to below func. work like charm

```
@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
    if((self.presentingViewController) != nil){
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        print("done")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = GlobalVariables.selectedMainIconName
         let image = UIImage(named: "back-btn")

         image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(Current[enter image description here][1]ViewController.back) )
    }

    func back() {
      self.navigationController?.popToViewController( self.navigationController!.viewControllers[ self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - 2 ], animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingToParent {

        //your code backView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target = "methodname"
func methodname ( ) {            
  //    enter code here
}
```

Try on this too.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  //empty your array
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem is nil when using the default (iOS provided) back button, which @StevenZ appears to be asking about.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to empty your `array` as you press your back button and pop to your previous `ViewController let` your `Array` which you loaded on this screen is

```
let settingArray  = NSMutableArray()
@IBAction func Back(sender: AnyObject) {
    self. settingArray.removeAllObjects()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest possible Swift 5 solution that doesn't require you to create a custom back button and give up all that UINavigationController left button functionality you get for free.

As **Brandon A** recommends above, you need need to implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in the view controller you want to interact with before returning to it. A good way is to create an unwind segue that you can perform manually or automatically and reuse the same code from a custom done button or the back button.

First, make your view controller of interest (the one you want to detect returning to) a delegate of the navigation controller in its `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Second, add an extension at the bottom of the file that overrides `navigationController(willShow:animated:)`

```
extension PickerTableViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              willShow viewController: UIViewController,
                              animated: Bool) {

        if let _ = viewController as? EditComicBookViewController {

            let selectedItemRow = itemList.firstIndex(of: selectedItemName)
            selectedItemIndex = IndexPath(row: selectedItemRow!, section: 0)

            if let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedItemIndex) {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "PickedItem", sender: selectedCell)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since your question included a `UITableViewController`, I included a way to get the index path of the row the user tapped.

Answer (score 1):

My preference was to **override the popViewController**  in the Navigation Controller. The advantages of this is:

1. Your app keeps the default Back Button look and animations, and you don't have to manage it. This is particularly helpful if a user has Large Text set on their phone, since the default back button will increase or decrease in size based on the user settings.
2. You can stop the view from popping altogether, unlike using viewWillDisappear.

First, create a custom Navigation Controller class (and be sure to assign it to the Navigation Controller in your Story Board or wherever your navigation controller is created):

```
class NavControllerWithBackButtonOverride: UINavigationController {

    var backButtonOverride: (() -> Void)? = nil

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {

        if backButtonOverride != nil {
            //if anything is assigned to the backButtonOverride the override will run
            self.backButtonOverride!()
            return nil
        } else {
            //otherwise the default popViewController will run
            return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Then enable/disable the override in your View Controller by assigning a value to the backButtonOverride variable:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.enableCustomBackButton()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.disableCustomBackButton()
}

/**
 Custom Back Button
 */

func customBackButtonAction() {
    print("DO THIS INSTEAD")
}

func enableCustomBackButton() {
    if let nav = self.navigationController as? NavControllerWithBackButtonOverride {
        nav.backButtonOverride = { self.customBackButtonAction() }
        nav.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }    
}

func disableCustomBackButton() {
    if let nav = self.navigationController as? NavControllerWithBackButtonOverride {
    nav.backButtonOverride = nil
    nav.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Note: I also disabled interactivePopGestureRecognizer because it was causing issues with the custom setup.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by calling/overriding `viewWillDisappear` and then accessing the stack of the `navigationController` like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let stack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count

    if stack >= 2 {
        // for whatever reason, the last item on the stack is the TaskBuilderViewController (not self), so we only use -1 to access it
        if let lastitem = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[stack! - 1] as? theViewControllerYoureTryingToAccess {
            // hand over the data via public property or call a public method of theViewControllerYoureTryingToAccess, like
            lastitem.emptyArray()
            lastitem.value = 5
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something in your Viewcontroller like

```
override func navigationShouldPopOnBackButton() -> Bool {
    self.backAction() //Your action you want to perform.
    return true
}
```

For complete answer use
[Detecting when the 'back' button is pressed on a navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228411/detecting-when-the-back-button-is-pressed-on-a-navbar/31410821#31410821)

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 5+ (Back button with alert control)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(PGWebViewController.back(sender:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
}


@objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Your payment process is not completed yet. Do you want to go back?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
         let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
             _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
         })
         alert.addAction(ok)
         let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in
         })
         alert.addAction(cancel)
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+ Xcode 14+**

I tried multiple ways to override default back button by appending and removing view controllers from navigation stack.

But below solution worked only.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(popToRoot))
}

@objc func popToRoot() {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply remove unnecessary controllers from the stack, something like this:

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAll(where: {
        $0 is FirstViewController || $0 is SecondWithPinController
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I solved it for my own problem

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(self.back(sender:))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target = self
}

@objc func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```