# How to make a arrow in UIBarButtonItem like back button arrow in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

How to make a arrow in custom `UIBarButtonItem` like back buttom arrow in the Swift? I want to move via previous controller and I make custom `UIBarButtonController` but it has not arrow.

[image]

Comment: The arrow is provided by a standard `UINavigationController`. Just embed your view controller in a Navigation Controller and push a new view controller onto the Navigation Controller stack (either by a `segue` or `pushViewController:animated:`) to get the arrow. It is nothing to do with `UIBarButtonItem`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use Attributed String and assign it to your UIButton
Use this string

`var str = "< Playlist Table"`

Use this tutorial for further detail http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/attributed-strings-tutorial-ios8-swift

It will Help.ThankYou

Comment: "← Back" looks okay. Name of the arrow emoji is `LEFTWARDS ARROW`

Answer (score 0):

**Custom Back Button**

For those of you are here to make a custom back button,
check this [similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed/37230710#37230710) which works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a navigation controller, this should appear automatically when you move from ViewController A to B.

To change the text "Playlist Table" in controller B, you need to set it on controller A.

Comment: I make custom UIBarButtonController but it has not arrow.