# Swift: Function Called when Back is pressed

Tags: swift

I would like to perform some actions when a user presses the "Back" button on my Navigation Controller.  Is there a Swift function that is called when this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
// Do Your Lines of Code ... 
}
```

Everytime when back button or Done is pressed or a view is popped out this function is called.. you need to override this..

Comment: Keep in mind using this will also be called if the viewController presents or pushes another viewController.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (copied and pasted from manecosta)

Replacing the button to a custom one as suggested on another answer is possibly not a great idea as you will lose the default behavior and style.

One other option you have is to implement the viewWillDisappear method on the View Controller and check for a property named isMovingFromParentViewController. If that property is true, it means the View Controller is disappearing because it's being removed (popped).

Should look something like:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()){
        // Your code...
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed) is the link to the other question

Answer (score 4):

Try to call this

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        print("isMovingFromParent()") // dismiss for push viewController
    }
    if self.isBeingDismissed {
        print("isBeingDismissed()") // dismiss for modal that doesn't has navigationController
    }
    if self.navigationController?.isBeingDismissed ?? false {
        print("navigationController?.isBeingDismissed()") // dismiss for modal that has navigationController
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more precise than the accepted question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    if parent == nil {
        // Back button Event handler
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this and the weird thing is that this function is called before I get to the view controller, as well as when I click the back button.  Unfortunately that will not work for me.  Adbul's function is called when I need it to be.

Comment: Abdul's function sometime will got some error if the current ViewController continue to push to another ViewController.

Comment: This method is not getting called at all

Comment: The function name is changed in Swift 4 (or 3) to `willMove(toParentViewController:)`.   If this method doesn't get called, is your viewController inside `UINavigationController`?  Does it has own back-button instead of the one supplied by `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5

"viewWillDisappear" call Every time for forward or backward.
But if you add this check it's call only when back from controller.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       
        if self.isMovingFromParent {
            print("Only back action")
        }
    }
```