# Detecting when back button is tapped in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I need to `resignFirstResponder()` on a text field when the user taps the back button in the navigation bar of the navigation controller, otherwise I get some error. The back button works as it should (the previous view gets shown) but I don't know where to do resign first responder. It's too late if I do it in `viewWillDisappear()` (I tried), and `prepareForSegue()` doesn't get called, so I need to somehow do it as soon as the back button gets tapped or at least before `viewWillDisappear()`. How do I detect that event?

Comment: It question was in stackoverflow - [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228411/detecting-when-the-back-button-is-pressed-on-a-navbar)
answer

Answer (score 2):

**Note: See first comment on question for simpler answer**

You could combine `NotificationCenter`and this post: [Execute action when back bar button of UINavigationController is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed) to make a custom back button (that looks the same). Just post a `Notification` in the action for the back button, and add an observer for the `Notification` on the `textfield` whose action calls `resignFirstResponder`. You would also need to make an image or draw an image in CoreGraphics for the arrow.