# How to set system's back button's (backBarButtonItem) selector?

Tags: ios, swift

[Systems back button on the navigation bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP27X.png)

I want this system's button which is on the navigationBar has two different actions.
 1. `navigationController?.popViewController` when device orientation is portrait as default action.
 2. rotate device orientation to portrait when device orientation is landscape. `UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")`

I can do it by create a new UIBarButtonItem and set it to `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

But it doesn't have system's left-arrow image and localize string.
I need this button has system's left-arrow image and localize string likes system's provide.

I tried to set action like

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(self.backToPortrait)
```

It wasn't work.

So how can I set action to this back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add action to that system back button. There are two alternatives.

1. Create your own back button. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed) is an example
2. Instead of managing orientation change, lock your previous view controller to have portrait mode only. So it can do auto rotation for you, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like I need to make left-arrow image and localize by myself with init(customView: UIView).

Comment: @蔡祥霖 Yup. Let me know if you have further question