# Go back to root when nav back button is press

Tags: ios, swift

I have the method to check when the back button in navigation bar is press and the method go back to root page but for some reason when `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` it only go back to the previous page. do anyone know how to go back to the root when navigation bar back button is pressed?

```
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)

    if parent == nil{
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }

}
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed) question he is asking how to what method can he use to customise his back button. In my code its able to detect when user press on back button and  `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`
 is suppose to bring the page back to the root page, however there are somethings in the system preventing my app to go back to the root page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute action when back bar button of UINavigationController is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not recommend what you are trying to achieve, but anyways here is a different solution without customizing the back button.

### Steps to implement

1. Create **CustomNavigationController** by subclassing
   `UINavigationController`
2. Override `popViewController(animated:)`
3. When `ViewController` conforms to `Navigationable` and

   - `shouldCustomNavigationControllerPopToRoot()` returns `true`, call `super.popToRootViewController`
   - Otherwise proceed with normally popping the `ViewController`

### Source Code

*Custom Navigation Controller*

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - Initializers

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)

        initialSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        initialSetup()
    }

    // MARK: - Setups

    private func initialSetup() {
        // DISCLAIMER: This code does not support `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, therefore we disable it
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }

    // MARK: - Overrides

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        if shouldNavigationPopToRoot {
            return super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)?.last
        }

        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers

    private var shouldNavigationPopToRoot: Bool {
        return (topViewController as? Navigationable)?.shouldCustomNavigationControllerPopToRoot() == true
    }
}
```

*View Controller conforming to `Navigationable`*

```
import UIKit

protocol Navigationable: class {
    func shouldCustomNavigationControllerPopToRoot() -> Bool
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, Navigationable {

    // MARK: - Protocol Conformance
    // MARK: Navigationable

    func shouldCustomNavigationControllerPopToRoot() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

### Output

[image: CustomNavigationController]

Comment: it dose work however this method will change all of the back button is there anyway to change selected back button?

Comment: @KUROYUKI Yes it is possible via a protocol, I will update the answer!

Comment: Hi @EridB now when I am trying to use the same code on swift 4.2 its giving me an "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code" error do you know why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

i think the best way is to create your own custom back button at this page

```
override func viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.back(sender:)))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
}

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Perform your custom actions
    // ...
    // Go back to the root ViewController
    _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

credit to this answer by 'fr33g' : [Execute action when back bar button of UINavigationController is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed)