# Swift - iOS - Modify back button path

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have the following view controllers:

A -> B -> ... Z

Now let's say I'm at view controller B. If I click its back button, I'll return to view controller A. My question is: How can I make B's back button go to another view controller, say view controller Z, instead of A?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term unwind?

Comment: You need to return to your root view controller and from there segue to the controller you want to present.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950343/go-back-to-root-when-nav-back-button-is-press do that first and after segue to your viewcontroller.

Comment: Consider not using a back button, but instead setting `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to a `UIBarButtonItem` that will push Z, or set `navigationController.viewControllers`. Using the Back button for adding view controllers would probably be confusing to users.