# Toolbar disappear after push

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I have FormViewController that I made full programmatically with Eureka form builder ([link](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka)). I dont have view controller in storyboard for that. Class name of that view controller is NewPasswordVC. When I click od add bar button I open NewPasswordVC with this code:

```
let newPasswordVC = NewPasswordVC()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newPasswordVC, animated: true)
```

I open NewPasswordVC but when I go back in root view controller my bottom toolbar disappear. Why? How to fix this?

This is storyboard:
[image]

This is my problem in gif:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code snippet of your Generate pass VC? That might help in finding out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem I found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667598/7452767)

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?){
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)
    if parent == nil{
        self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak about Eureka specifically, but chances are the `UIViewController` being pushed in has [hidesBottomBarWhenPushed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed) set to `true`.

So I would look into setting it to `false`, which can be done programmatically.

Comment: It does not work. The toolbar is hidden when I enter a new VC, where I can write a code that will be executed when I snap back on the navigation?