# How to get difference between interactivePopGestureRecognizer and arrow pop

Tags: ios, swift

I want to log analytics when user pop `UIViewController` with swipe gesture (`interactivePopGestureRecognizer`) or pressed on default back button on navigationController. I find a way to detect when user using swipe gesture:

```
extension AppCoordinator: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let coordinator = navigationController.topViewController?.transitionCoordinator {
            coordinator.notifyWhenInteractionChanges(handleInteraction)
        }
    }

    func handleInteraction(context: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) {
        guard !context.isCancelled else {
            return
        }
       //LOG EVENT HERE
    }
}
```

But what about back button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713747/execute-action-when-back-bar-button-of-uinavigationcontroller-is-pressed

Comment: they use isMovingFromParent or delegate method. But I also want to detect if this back button or swipe gesture. How can I do that?

Comment: There is so many ways to do this. you can create custom action for back button to decent that back button was tapped.

Comment: how can I create custom action?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54862131/4311935