# Detect or get notified when the user taps the back button on the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a fairly basic app which has a `UINavigationController` with a root `UIViewController` which we can call home.

From the home screen, we push an article `UIViewController` onto the existing `UINavigationController`

From the article `UIViewController`, we can push several other `UIViewControllers`.

We want to add some analytics to track the back button tap event.

**What I've tried and their limitations**

1. Adding a custom bar button item

I've tried doing that based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27713813/1619193 - however, we lose the default appearance as well as the default behavior of swiping to go back by going with this approach.

2. Adding code to `viewWillDisappear`

On it's own, this would not work as `viewWillDisappear` would also be called when we push / present other view controllers, however, I did come across an [improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51393266/1619193):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.isMovingFromParent {
        print("we are being popped")
    }
}
```

The limitation here is that we also would also track any instances of programatically popping rather than purely the user going back.

3. Other options

I also came across some alternative solutions of [a custom UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69251166/1619193) and also [conforming to the UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133107/1619193) however they seem to have the same limitations as option 2 I believe ?

What would be the best / right way to detect when the user taps the default back button provided by iOS ?

Comment: How about setting some flag when you programmatically go back, so that you know which ones are caused by the user?

Comment: Thats a good idea @Sweeper - might probably have to go this route. Wondering if there was a delegate / notification approach that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 16+, you can assign your custom action to [`backAction`](https://self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:%20true)). The documentation says

> If a back button already appears in the navigation bar, setting this property replaces its action without modifying its appearance.

So this won't be triggered if you dismiss the VC programmatically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    navigationItem.backAction = UIAction { _ in
        print("Pressed back button!")

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        // or perform an unwind segue, or whatever else you need to do to dismiss the VC
    }
}
```

Comment: This works really well for iOS 16+. Due to a requirement, we need to support iOS 15+, do you have any suggestions for iOS 15 besides the flag you suggested in your comments ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank I don't, unfortunately.