# How to check for self with contains() in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to check if the back button on my view controller was pressed but I'm having a hard time detecting this in Swift.

With this code:

```
    if (contains(self.navigationController?.viewControllers, self)) {
        println("Back button not pressed")
    } else {
        self.updateSearchQueryModel()
    }
```

I am getting the error:

> Could not find an overload for contains that accepts the supplied arguments.

I did get the result that I wanted in another fashion but I am still confused as to why this error is happening.

Why is this happening? Can I not check if self exists in an array?

Source of original code in Objective C that I couldn't translate to Swift:
[Setting action for back button in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller)

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
       // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
       // in the navigation stack.  
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

*Please do not tell me how to detect that the back button was pressed.* I already figured that out here.

Source of solution to objective: [Detecting when the 'back' button is pressed on a navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228411/detecting-when-the-back-button-is-pressed-on-a-navbar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of the `viewControllers` property, you notice that it's `[AnyObject]!` and not `[UIViewController]!`.

The `contains` function requires that the sequence element implements the `Equatable` protocol, which `AnyObject` doesn't.

The solution is to make an explicit downcast of that array, using optional binding:

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    if (contains(viewControllers, self)) {
        println("Back button not pressed")
    } else {
        self.updateSearchQueryModel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Swift but try this:

```
if let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    if contains(controllers, self) {
        DLog("!")
    }
}
```

You're getting error because you're passing optional as `contains()`'s first argument

Comment: You're correct that its being optional is a issue, but if that was it, we could solve it by simply unwrapping the optional. The more serious problem is that `contains` requires the object to conform to `Equatable`. In your optional binding process, you coincidentally addressed this second, more fundamental problem.