# What event fires when a UIView is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

When dismissing a `UIViewController` via the back button, are there any events that I can trap?

I want to write a couple of user defaults when the `UIViewController` is exiting.

Comment: I would suggest you read this Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) regarding view lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Both the methods `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` should be called at this time.

Answer (score -1):

willMoveToParentViewController might be your friend here

[Detecting when the 'back' button is pressed on a navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228411/detecting-when-the-back-button-is-pressed-on-a-navbar/17551952#17551952)

Comment: "When dismissing a UIViewController via the back button" in this specific case, using willMoveToParentViewController is a way to go, it's a well-known solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228411/detecting-when-the-back-button-is-pressed-on-a-navbar/17551952#17551952

Comment: Then you should explain that in your answer - What you have here is more suited as a comment

Comment: No, -1 is for poor answers

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. Thanks for your comment, I hope that in the end the answer will help Scott