# show Admob interstitial when with nav back button press iOS Swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios7, ios5

i have two view controllers imageViewController and InfoViewController. i want my ad to show when the user click on back button from InfoViewController

```
class imageViewController: UIViewController , GADInterstitialDelegate {
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
 override func viewDidLoad() {

         self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
         super.viewDidLoad()
}
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        let interstitial: GADInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        print("req sent")
        return interstitial
    }
    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        if (interstitial.isReady) {
            print("ad ready")
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }}
     func interstitialDidDismissScreen(interstitial: GADInterstitial) {
    }
```

How should i call it with back button click from infoViewController to ImageViewCroller. i also failed to solve this problem with global variable since i am new to iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to call it in one of the `UIViewController`'s methods. For example:

```
isMovingFromParentViewController()
```

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingFromParentViewController).

**EDIT:**

Actually, if you want to have a VC as a delegate, you should call it from the parent VC, otherwise you will lose the delegate by popping it with the back button.

You can do it in a few ways. One would be to use a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). Here, you would put your callback methods in the first VC and have a property in your second VC like so:

```
var onBack:()->()?
```

And you would need to set it's value when showing the second VC (for example in `prepareForSegue` method):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? InfoViewController {
        destination.onBack = { ()->() in
            self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the second view controller do this:

```
override func isMovingFromParentViewController() -> Bool {
    onBack?()
}
```

That is not tested btw:)

Comment: Thanks Konrad for your replay. i call         
 self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
while creating an exit button in infoVC but still i faced the same problem can u direct me more specifically ?

Comment: Ok, so that probably doesn't work because by pressing the Back button, you are popping your VC and at the same time the delegate for your interstitial. So either you have a globally accessible class where you handle interstitials, or you call it from the parent VC. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: i get the Error  " Class infoViewController" has no initializer"

Comment: You are probably using a not optional property and you don't initialize it. Hard to say which one without seeing the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way for me to detect ios back pressed and show admob interstitial ad on backPressed is by using `willMoveToParentViewController` or `didMoveToParentViewController` in my childViewController, in your case `InfoViewController`.

I create my interstitial admob interstitial instance on appDelegate. So, I can use it globally and only use one instance/shared instance (i think )

then just call it on `willMoveToParentViewController` or `didMoveToParentViewController` like this. Both are almost the same. (`willMoveToParentViewController` will just be called ahead (my observation: ad will show while transitioning back) of `didMoveToParentViewController` (my observation: ad will show when fully transitioned back ))

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent)
    if parent == nil {
        appDelegate.showInterstitialAd()
    }
}
```

or

```
override func didMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMoveToParentViewController(parent)
    if parent == nil {
        appDelegate.showInterstitialAd()
    }

}
```

Got the idea from this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551952

PS. calling `interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self) on`interstitialDidReceiveAd` is not the best way to call it since you don't have control when it will show.

Comment: Thanks, i will use this next time

Answer (score 1):

it will show ad just on back Press

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    var showAd = true
viewdidload {
self.createandLoadInterstitial()
}
 func createAndLoadInterstitial()  {
         interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.loadRequest(request)

    } 
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if (interstitial.isReady && showAd) {
            showAd = false
            print("iterstitalMain is ready")
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
        }
        else{
        showAd = true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

perfect tested code for add interstitial ads. in back button.
add this code in secondviewController. no need to add anything in FirstViewcontroller.

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial()  {
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "your id")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.loadRequest(request)

}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if (interstitial.isReady && showAd) {
        showAd = false
        print("iterstitalMain is ready")
        interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(parentViewController!)
        self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated function of the answer on top.

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.willMove(toParent: parent)
        if parent == nil {
            if interstitial.isReady {
              interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            } else {
              print("Ad wasn't ready")
            }
        }
    }``
```