# Unified UIViewController "became frontmost" detection?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

In my mind, these situations are all parallel:

- My view controller presented another view controller fullscreen, which has now been dismissed
- My view controller presented another view controller not fullscreen, which has now been dismissed
- My view controller presented a popover, which has now been dismissed
- My view controller pushed another view controller, which has now been popped

In every case, my view controller ceased to be the "frontmost" view controller, and then became "frontmost" again. I find it curious that iOS has no single blanket "became frontmost" event sent to my view controller that covers all these situations.

I think I can cover each of those cases *individually*, and I think those are all the cases I need to cover, but the resulting code is confusing and scattered:

- `viewDidAppear` detects popping of a pushed view controller and dismissal of a fullscreen presented view controller
- popover delegate message detect dismissal of a popover
- not sure what detects dismissal of a nonfullscreen presented view controller

How do people handle this coherently and elegantly?

Comment: `became frontmost` – I have very consistent results with `UIViewController`'s `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder`. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder). It's not working for child view controllers, though.

Comment: @bteapot I sure never thought of that, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Good question. I've been struggling with this for a while (keep punting on it), hoping to figure out a way to inject a proxy responder object between controllers (swizzling?), to then detect these transitions without spilling code into the "otherwise context-free" controllers.

Comment: I played around a bit with swizzling `becomeFirstResponder` — and it seems to not be called on the new frontmost when a presented view controller is dismissed.

I don't think that's super surprising since it could trigger UI that might be disruptive — but it means it won't work for this purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What the cases have in common is not the appearance of the original view controller but the disappearance of the presented/pushed view controller. Therefore, one simple and clear solution seems to be a protocol-and-delegate architecture. Declare a pair of protocols, as follows:

```
protocol Home : class {
    func comingHome()
}
protocol Away : class {
    var home : Home? {get set}
}
extension Away where Self : UIViewController {
    func notifyComingHome() {
        if self.isBeingDismissed || self.isMovingFromParent {
            self.home?.comingHome()
        }
    }
}
```

- The home view controller must adopt Home, and must set each view controller's `home` to `self` when it presents or pushes it.
- The presented or pushed view controllers must adopt Away, and must implement `viewWillDisappear` as follows:

  ```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      self.notifyComingHome()
  }
  ```

This works for the four cases listed in the question. It's a pity, though, that Cocoa Touch doesn't do this for you automatically.

---

**EDIT** This approach has become even more important in my apps now that iOS 13 has forced nonfullscreen presented view controllers upon us. Also, I have subclassed UIAlertController so that it conforms to Away.

Comment: Accepting my own answer for now, but if there’s a better way I’d like to hear about it.

Comment: This approach doesn't work when you presenting a view controller which contains another view controller. Both of those VC return `isBeingDismissed` and `isMovingFromParent` false when dismissing

Comment: Also, `viewWillDisappear` called even if you just start dragging the modal view controller down on iOS 13. But starting dragging the VC down doesn't mean it's going to be dismissed.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Fine, give a better answer. I need one.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev @matt Leaving this here, in case anyone needs it: I implemented `self.home?.comingHome()` in `viewDidDisappear` instead of `viewWillDisappear` and it calls back only when the view is actually dismissed (i.e. after dragging)

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to take the Coordinator approach like in a MVVM-C style architecture. You never directly change view hierarchy in a VC but always call into the Coordinator to do it for you. coordinator.showDetails(...)

Additionally you define a `viewDidBecomeForemost` method in your VCs that the coordinator can invoke when returning to a VC.